# Futuristic setting where citizens pay via "ID chips"

Tags: story-identification

This is a book I never finished so I can only give a brief summary of the beginning of the book.

From what I remember, the story is a futuristic setting where citizens pay via "ID chips" and they can hire people and slaves that way.

A girl is trying to become a maid in order to get travel via a spaceship to another territory. She encounters a guy who refuses to help her, but then ends up buying her as his "maid" and of course he insults her and has her do demeaning chores.

But a series of events occur and he loses his memory and she pretends that she is now the owner of him.

At one point I remember she uses his "ID chip" to buy herself an extravagant dress.

Comment: How long ago do you remember reading this book?

Comment: The Body Institute by Carol Riggs? - It's very recent though...https://pennydreadfulbooks.me/2015/09/page/4/

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.